# Alternative to decentralize exchange on Ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic, decentralized-exchange, gnosis

Because of the block time lag, The decentralize exchanges built on Ethereum suffers from a Front running problem.

Gnosis works on Dutch exchange concept where orders are executed in Bulk eliminating any party to have advantage over another party in terms of Trade.

My question is, Is there any other strategy better than Dutch Exchange.

Comment: Use an exchange that uses LibSubmarine to circumvent front-running. (https://hackernoon.com/libsubmarine-temporarily-hide-transactions-on-ethereum-cheaply-6910191f46f2)